# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.Request.**get** returned null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In a ASP.Net Core 3.1 project, I have a "base" controller which I inherit from `ControllerBase`, and looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
public abstract class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    protected readonly IMapper mapper;
    protected readonly ILogger logger;

    protected BaseController(
        IMapper mapper, 
        ILogger logger)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.logger = logger;

        var ok = Request.HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("value", out object value);
    }
}
```

And then my controllers that inherit from it, such as:

```
[Route("api/[Controller]"]
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public MyController(
        IMapper mapper, 
        ILogger<MyController> logger, 
        /*...some other services injected here...*/) : base(mapper, logger)
    { }
}
```

I have a middleware setup that sets the "value" item in the header's `Items` collection. The value is being set as expected.

However, as soon as I hit the the base controller's constructor, all properties are null (Request, HttpConext, ControllerContext, etc).

The above setup used to work fine with WebApi2.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Make your ctors `public`

Comment: @JohanP Typo, ctor is public in code.

Comment: @dcg Sorry, another typo!! base ctor is being called in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IHttpContextAccessor` for access to `HttpContext` in asp.net core.

first you must register `IHttpContextAccessor` in `ConfigureServices` method like this

```cs
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

then access to `HttpContext` from DI

```cs
 protected BaseController(
        IMapper mapper, 
        ILogger logger,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.logger = logger;

        var ok = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("value", out object value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it in ASP.Net Core 3+ is to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into the controller and then register it as a Singleton.

As I'm using Autofac to handle my DI, I did this by adding:

```
        builder.RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>()
             .As<IHttpContextAccessor>()
             .SingleInstance();
```